# ReferenceError when the variable is being logged in console?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, expo

A followed up issue from: [orderByKey is not a function in reactjs expo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75506942/orderbykey-is-not-a-function-in-reactjs-expo)

Having a issue where my variable `random` is generating a random number for me to use to get a random node in firebase realtime DB but I am getting a reference error even though I have console log the variable `random` and it is giving me a value.

Here is my code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import {db} from '../firebase'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ref, get, orderByKey, limitToFirst} from 'firebase/database'

const SubScreen2 = () => {
  
  
  
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  
  
  useEffect (() => {
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random)
      return get(ref(db, `food/`), orderByKey(), limitToFirst(random + 1))
    }).then(snapshot => {
      const randomKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[random];
      setToDoData(snapshot.val()[randomKey]);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }, [])
  console.log(todoData)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {todoData ? (
        <View>
          <Text>{todoData.Description}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.Location}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.Halal}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.OH}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen2
```

My console log:

[image]

I don't get how am I getting a reference error even though the log for `random` has a value of 96?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with this line:

```
const randomKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[random];
```

The variable is out of scope as you declare it in the previous block.

Maybe you can do something like...

```
  useEffect (() => {
    let random = 0;
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random)
      return get(ref(db, `food/`), orderByKey(), limitToFirst(random + 1))
    }).then(snapshot => {
      const randomKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[random];
      ...
```

Comment: Make sense. At first when I tried this method it didnt work so I tried using UseState instead but it also didnt work. Restarting the app and going back to this worked nicely.  Thanks ! Sorry to keep bothering you but I have one my question. Is it possible to help me take a look and help me identify what is wrong? Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510591/usestate-is-undefined-although-it-is-set