# How to properly get a random node from firebase realtime DB via react JS expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, expo

Follow up issue from [ReferenceError when the variable is being logged in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509803/referenceerror-when-the-variable-is-being-logged-in-console/75509988#75509988).

Console log:

[image]

Current code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import {db} from '../firebase'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ref, get, orderByKey, limitToFirst} from 'firebase/database'

const SubScreen2 = () => {
  
  
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber]= useState([])
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  
  
  useEffect (() => {
    var random = 0
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random)
      return get(ref(db, `food/`), orderByKey(), limitToFirst(random + 1))
    }).then(snapshot => {
      const randomKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[random];
      setToDoData(snapshot.val()[randomKey]);
      
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }, [])
  console.log(todoData)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {todoData ? (
        <View>
          <Text>{todoData.Description}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.Location}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.Halal}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.OH}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen2
```

I couldnt get a random node via `const randomKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[random]` as `snapshot.val()[random]` gives me undefined. What is the correct way get this random node according to the random value I can get?

Part of my database:

```
{
  "food": {
    "Bakery": {
      "Bakery Cuisine": {
        "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
        "Halal": "Yes",
        "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-20 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
        "OH": "Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 7 PM, Sun Closed"
      }
    },
    "Beverage": {
      "Beverage": {
        "Description": "Within the South Spine food court",
        "Halal": "No",
        "Location": "21 Nanyang Link, Singapore 637371",
        "OH": "Mon - Fri: 7 30 am to 8 pm, Sat - Sun/PH Closed"
      },
      "Beverages": {
        "Description": "Within North Spine Koufu",
        "Halal": "No",
        "Location": "76 Nanyang Dr, #02-03 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 637331",
        "OH": "Mon - Fri : 7 am to 8 pm, Sat : 7 am to 3 pm, Sun Closed"
      },
      "Boost": {
        "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
        "Halal": "No",
        "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-11 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
        "OH": "Mon - Fri : 10 am to 9 pm, Sat - Sun: 10 am to 6 pm"
      },
      
    "Total": 120,
```

I require the **node's name** and the value under it which are **Description ,Halal, OH and Location**

**Update**: Using the provided solution

My console logs shows me the 4 (Description, Halal, Location and OH) are undefined

[image]

My current DB:

Part of my database:
[image]

```
{
  "Bakery": {
    "Bakery Cuisine": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "Yes",
      "Latitude": 1.34714,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-20 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68066,
      "OH": "Mon - Sat : 8 AM to 7 PM, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 1
    }
  },
  "Beverage": {
    "Beverage": {
      "Description": "Within the South Spine food court",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34253,
      "Location": "21 Nanyang Link, Singapore 637371",
      "Longitude": 103.68243,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri: 7 30 am to 8 pm, Sat - Sun/PH Closed",
      "ShopNo": 2
    },
    "Beverages": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Koufu",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34708,
      "Location": "76 Nanyang Dr, #02-03 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 637331",
      "Longitude": 103.68002,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 7 am to 8 pm, Sat : 7 am to 3 pm, Sun Closed",
      "ShopNo": 3
    },
    "Boost": {
      "Description": "Within North Spine Plaza",
      "Halal": "No",
      "Latitude": 1.34735,
      "Location": "50 Nanyang Ave, #01-11 North Spine Plaza, Singapore 639798",
      "Longitude": 103.68036,
      "OH": "Mon - Fri : 10 am to 9 pm, Sat - Sun: 10 am to 6 pm",
      "ShopNo": 4
    },
"Total": 89,
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data that lives at path `food/Total` in your database (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Why do you use the same random keys for two different objects? They won't be the same between the two

Comment: I have added my part of my JSON file in the post. And what do you mean by two different objects with same random key?

Comment: @L.Calvin are you sure you are getting what you expect at `snapshot.val()[randomKey]` here? Maybe try console logging this and see what sort of values you get?

Comment: I am get ```Undefined``` which means its not the correct way to get snapshot of a random node. I am unsure of the correct way to get the snapshot of a random node

Comment: If I were you, I would simply grab the snapshot and do the manipulation after. You could convert the child nodes into arrays and flatten it then filter on the single array at random.

Comment: Do you mean snapshot of ```/food``` and then manipulation? Is it possible to show me how is it done like what you said? @AlexGill

Comment: How do I convert the child nodes and flatten it to filter the output randomly ? I still cant seem to do it @AlexGill

Answer (score 0):

To get a random node from Firebase Realtime Database in React Native, you can modify the code as follows:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import {db} from '../firebase'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ref, get, orderByKey, limitToFirst} from 'firebase/database'

const SubScreen2 = () => {
  
  
  const [randomNumber, setRandomNumber]= useState([])
  const [todoData, setToDoData] = useState([])
  
  
  useEffect (() => {
    get(ref(db, "food/Total")).then(snapshot => {
      const count = snapshot.val();
      const random = Math.floor((Math.random() * count));
      console.log(random)
      return get(ref(db, `food/`), orderByKey(), limitToFirst(random + 1))
    }).then(snapshot => {
      const randomNode = snapshot.val()[Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]];
      const { Description, Halal, Location, OH } = randomNode;
      setToDoData({ Description, Halal, Location, OH });
      
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  }, [])
  console.log(todoData)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {todoData ? (
        <View>
          <Text>{todoData.Description}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.Location}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.Halal}</Text>
          <Text>{todoData.OH}</Text>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

export default SubScreen2
```

In this code, we first fetch the total count of nodes under the `food` node. Then we generate a random number between 0 and the count. We use `orderByKey()` and `limitToFirst()` methods to get the node at the random index. Then we extract the node's properties and set them in the `todoData` state variable. We access the node's properties using destructuring and the property names. Finally, we display the node's properties in the JSX.

Good look!

Comment: Hey! Firstly, thanks for taking the time to read and help me on this issue but I am still facing some trouble (2 issues). I am using the above code you have suggested but (1st issue) my Description, Halal, Location, OH are currently undefined in my console logs. (2nd issue), it generate the random value according to total but the ```randomNode``` is always returning me "Bakery Cuisine's detail. How come?

Comment: Also I dont know if it affects but the amount of things under each shop in my database has been increased but no changes has been done to Description, Location, Halal and OH. I have updated the post with what is happening currently. Is it possible to help me take a look at it and identify how to fix the issue?

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?